# setting up snort 2.9.x with barnyard2

Tags: centos6, php5, snort, barnyard2

These how to guides on the interent are outdated also the software it is relying on is not up to date with PHP5.5. I have done some hacks with ACID and ADODB to make part sof the gui to work. I have followed this guid to set up barnyard2 http://sathisharthars.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/configuring-snort-with-barnyard-snortreport-acid-in-ubuntu-14-04/ I have tried to follow other guids but have not able to successfulyl start snort and barnayrd and make the ACID gui work with any results. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=start+snort+with+barnyard2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=yPXMU7OvCKfY8gfn2IGADQ

Problems i face with snort

```
  /usr/local/bin/snort -D -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i eth0 /usr/local/bin/barnyard2 -c /etc/snort/etc/barnyard2.conf -d /var/log/snort -f snort.u2 -w /var/log/snort/barnyard2.waldo -D
```

above line fails with the option `w`

```
  FATAL ERROR: Invalid option: w.
```

If i take w out i get next error

```
  FATAL ERROR: /etc/snort/etc/barnyard2.conf(27) Unknown config directive: reference_file.
```

I am not able to start snort.

I start barnyard2 and i see the follwoing erro in log files

```
barnyard2 -c /etc/snort/etc/barnyard2.conf -f merged.log

WARNING: Ignoring corrupt/truncated waldofile '/var/log/snort/barnyard2.waldo'
Jul 21 12:04:18 website-dev barnyard2: ERROR: Unable to open directory '' (No such file or directory)
Jul 21 12:04:18 website-dev barnyard2: ERROR: Unable to find the next spool file!
```

I have managed to make ACID load on apache after quite a bit of hacking to make it compatible with php5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use vm centos 7 64 bit minimal install
- disbale selinex and firewall

  systemctl stop firewalld

  systemctl disable firewalld
- update server
- [https://www.snort.org/documents/4 pdf]
- https://www.snort.org/downloads

  yum update -y
    yum install gcc flex bison zlib zlib-devel libpcap libpcap-devel pcre pcre-devel libdnet libdnet-devel tcpdump wget net-tools mariadb-server -y
- get libdnetdebug from http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15290376/dir/redhat_el_6/com/libdnet-debuginfo-1.12-6.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

> ```
>   rpm -ivh libdnet-debuginfo-1.12-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
>   cd /usr/local/src
>   wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/snort-2.9.6.2.tar.gz
>   wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/daq-2.0.2.tar.gz
>
>   # install daq
>   tar -zxvf daq-2.0.2.tar.gz
>   cd daq-2.0.2
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install
>   cd /usr/local/lib
>   ldconfig -v /usr/local/lib
>
>   # install snort
>   cd /usr/local/src/snort-2.9.6.2
>   ./configure --enable-sourcefire
>   make
>   make install
>   cd /usr/local/lib
>   ldconfig -v /usr/local/lib
>
>   cd /etc
>   mkdir -p snort
>   cd snort
>   cp /usr/local/src/snort-2.9.6.2/etc/* .
>   # get latest rule set
>   wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/registered/snortrules-snapshot-2962.tar.gz
>   tar -zxvf snortrules-snapshot-2962.tar.gz
>   cp ./etc/* .
>   touch /etc/snort/rules/white_list.rules /etc/snort/rules/black_list.rules
>
>   #configure
>   groupadd -g 40000 snort
>   useradd snort -u 40000 -d /var/log/snort -s /sbin/nologin -c SNORT_IDS -g snort
>   chown -R snort:snort *
>   chown -R snort:snort /var/log/snort
> ```

- modify snort.conf
- ** var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
- ** ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.1.0/24
- ** ipvar EXTERNAL_NET !$HOME_NET
- ** var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
- ** var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules
- ** var WHITE_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
- ** var BLACK_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
- ## configure

  ```
       cd /usr/local/src
       chown -R snort:snort *
       chmod -R 700 *
       chown -R snort:snort snort_dynamicsrc
       chmod -R 700 snort_dynamicsrc
       cd /usr/local/lib
       chown -R snort:snort snort*
       chown -R snort:snort pkgconfig
       chmod -R 700 snort*
       chmod -R 700 pkgconfig
       chown -R snort:snort daq-modules-config
       chown -R snort:snort u2*
       chmod -R 700 daq-modules-config
       chmod 700 u2*
       cd /etc
       chown -R snort:snort snort
       chmod -R 700 snort
       mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
       chown -R snort:snort /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
       chmod -R 700 /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
  ```
- get startup script from https://www.snort.org/documents
- need to edit config for stream5 to get rid of warnings as there is a 1mb limit http://manual.snort.org/node17.html#SECTION00322600000000000000

  snort -q -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i ens34 -D
- increase rx on interface http://www.gamelinux.org/?page_id=284

  ethtool -G ens34 rx 4096

  - for gui use '''Snorby''' https://snorby.org/